# Get a solution of of 2nd order PDE.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have: 
$$(x-y) u_{xy} - u_x + u_y = 0\tag{1}$$
i have to get the solution:
$$u(x,y) = \frac{X(x) - Y(y)}{x-y}$$
to solve this at first let, 
                      $$v = (x-y)u\\
                      u = \frac{v}{x-y}$$
then i can derive the derivatives of u:
                   $$u_x = -\frac{v}{(x-y)^2}\\ 
                       u_y = \frac{v}{(x-y)^2 }$$
now using (1) equation we get 
  $$ u_{xy}= -\frac{2v}{(x-y)^3} $$

Now i want to to integrate this equation w.r.t x, y. but what is the possible steps for integration. Could you please help to find out the solution.?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Answer (score 0):

Define $u = \frac{v}{x-y}$.
Then 
$$u_x=\frac{v_x}{x-y}-\frac{v}{(x-y)^2}
\qquad 
u_y=\frac{v_y}{x-y}+\frac{v}{(x-y)^2}\\
u_{xy} =
\frac{v_x}{(x-y)^2}+\frac{v_{xy}}{x-y}-\frac{v_y}{(x-y)^2}-\frac{2 v}{(x-y)^3}
$$

Substitute into $(1)$ to get
$$\frac{v_x}{(x-y)}+v_{xy}-\frac{v_y}{x-y}-\frac{2 v}{(x-y)^2}-\left(\frac{v_x}{x-y}-\frac{v}{(x-y)^2}\right)+\left(\frac{v_y}{x-y}+\frac{v}{(x-y)^2}\right)=0$$
Reduce it to get
$${v_{xy}}=0$$
which gives $v(x,y)=X(x)-Y(y)$ as required.